# Magento 2 - Paypal Error "We can't start Express Checkout."

Tags: magento, paypal, magento2

I have just finished a new install of Magento 2 and have tried setting up PayPal as the payment gateway, however it keeps returning the error 'We can't start Express Checkout.'. I have entered the correctly credentials, and can't seem to find away around this.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the system.log files I found that when submitting the checkout and proceeding to PayPal the system was calling a table that did not exist (I had previously changed my table prefix).

Strangely Magento 2 stores some table names in the 'sales_sequence_meta' and if you change your table prefix the names in this table also need to be revised.

There is not too much information on this out there.